# Get inserted document directly in RethinkDB

Tags: database, mongodb, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have been starting with RethinkDB. I have gone through the documentation. I have a simple use case of returning the inserted document when a POST call is made. This is something I have done so far.

```
router.post('/user', jsonParser, async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const connection = await conn;

  const { name, email, employeeId } = req.body;
  // Email is primary key
  consumerTable.insert({
    name,
    email,
    employeeId,
  }).run(connection, (err: any, result: any) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      consumerTable.get(email).run(connection, (innerErr: any, userResult: any) => {
        if(innerErr) {
          throw innerErr;
        } else {
          res.send({
            data: {
              ...userResult
            },
            responseCode: 200,
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any way to get the inserted object in the insert result itself. I read a lot of documentation, but didn't find anything useful.

Any help would be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `returnChanges` option of the `insert` command as specified in [the documentation](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/insert). It should look like this:

```
consumerTable.insert({
    name,
    email,
    employeeId,
}, { returnChanges: true }).run(connection, async (err: any, cursor: any) => {
    const data = await cursor.toArray();
    // .error should be undefined, unless... an error happened!
    // not sure about the format though, console.log data to check it really is an array
    res.send({ data: data[0].new_val, error: data[0].error });
});
```